# Maximum Likelihood Estimate for Two Normal RV's with the same parameter

Tags: statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

I have two different independent, normally distributed random samples that have the same parameters. $X_1$ ... $X_n$ is distributed $N(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and $Y_1$ ... $Y_n$ is distributed $N(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$. If $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu$ and $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma$, the MLE of these would just be derived the same as any normal random distribution, right?

I'm assuming yes because if $\mu_1=\mu_2$ and $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$, both of these random variables (and the technical "third" rv) should be the same. I just wanted confirmation that I'm correct before doing all the work and finding out that this isn't the right approach.

I don't want anyone to calculate the MLE for me. I just want to make sure I'm right. Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear what you're computing the MLE of, and what data you're using. Do you want to estimate the grand mean of $X_1,\dots,Y_n$ or just the $X_i$ and just the $Y_i$?

Comment: That's the thing. I've assumed that I could use either one. We're trying to find the MLE of $\mu$, which is equal to both $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you know that $\mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu$, then there are three MLEs for $\mu$, depending on which dataset you use. If the variances are all the same, you should use the full data set $\{X_1,\dots,X_n,Y_1,\dots,Y_n\}$ since the whole sample is iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Using only the $X$ group or $Y$ group gives you a lower Fisher information. If the variances are not the same, use the one with the lower variance (if that is known), since $\mathrm{Var}(\hat\mu) = \sigma^2/n$.

Comment: If you really believe $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n, Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ is one random sample of size $2n$ from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ then go ahead with the theoretical exercise of getting MLEs $\hat \mu$ and $\hat \sigma^2.$ But In practice, I would worry about combining two datasets possibly taken at different times or under different conditions, I would do some 2-sample tests before going ahead with that.